# apache airflow not loading new dags to Web UI anymore

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver

I have an Apache Airflow v2.2.0 instance running on a linux server.
When I create a new dag I can see it listed with 'airflow dags list' but it doesn't show up in the web user interface.

I tried also to take out and bring back an existing dag with the same result: the dag is listed from console but doesn't load anymore to the Web UI.

did anyone ever experience something similar?

Comment: how did you deployed airflow (docker or directly in the host server)? and if you are using docker, are you running all the services in the same container or you have separate container for webserver and scheduler?

Comment: Hi @HusseinAwala, 
I am planning to move all to docker, but at the moment all the services are running on a Linux VM. I have been using this setup for a few months and I never faced any issues until yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

restarting the scheduler solved the issue